# Get Div class content html

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I get content of div class="dpBibHoldingStatement" ?
It can't be used with getElementByClass, because there are several same classes in the html. I can't show all the code.

```
<div class="dpBibTitle"> 
    <!-- please read c1063106, c1063117, c1044421, c1060576a before changing title -->
    <a id="recordDisplayLink2Component_0" href="/iii/encore/record/C__Rb4101617__Sapple__P0%2C1__Orightresult__X5?lang=eng&amp;suite=pearl">
                            The Apple experience : the secrets of delivering insanely great customer service</a>
                         / by Carmine Gallo
</div>
<div class="dpBibAuthor">
<!-- author -->
    <a id="authorDisplayLinkComponent_0" href="/iii/encore/search/C__SGallo%2C+Carmine.__Orightresult?lang=eng&amp;suite=pearl">
                        Gallo, Carmine.</a>
</div>
<div class="dpBibHoldingStatement">
    Circulation Collection&nbsp;
    HF5415.5 .G356 2012  &nbsp;
    DUE 10-03-13OFF CAMPUS&nbsp;
    &nbsp;
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the div an ID and use `innerHTML`:

```
 <div id="yourDiv">
     Content
 </div>
```

Then using JavaScript do:

```
 var contents = document.getElementById("yourDiv").innerHTML;
 alert(contents);
```

Comment: put in a console.log, so he can read the contents properly in a webkit inspector

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not `getElementByClass`. It's `getElementsByClassName`.

When you run `document.getElementsByClassName("label-key")` on this page at developer tools, it'll show you an array of `label-key` items. You can get any item that you want from that array.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `document.getElementsByClassName[n]` to target the (n-1)th element on the page, or you attach an ID to it and use `document.getElementById(id)`.